# Live Server extention not rendering the page correctly

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Hello and thanks for the help in advance.

Recently I've formatted my Pc. It has now a fresh windows 10 pro install. Installed vscode and live server extension. Then I noticed it isn't rendering the list correctly:

[image: My problem]

The weird part is that when I configure Live Server to open chrome in private mode, the UL renders fine. I tried to clean all the navigation data from chrome, no success.

My chrome extensions are Grammarly, Tab Reloader, adblocker, and EPUB reader. Is it possible that the extensions are the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What you mean list is not rendering correctly? You mean the `<li> </li>`?

Comment: Are you missing list bullets?

Comment: Yes, it should render list bullets and let some space on the left. 
I'm learning web development, and I'm still on the very beginning, so I wasted time thinking my code had a problem, when in fact Live Server wasn't rendering it correctly. Besides, now that I know it won't render pages the right way, how can I trust it for more complex styles that I want to learn? How will I know If my code is the problem or the extension? It'll turn debugging a nightmare. Sorry, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Found a (not ideal) solution. Uninstalled the EPUB reader extension and the code rendered correctly.